# What is wrong in this program to convert decimal to binary?

Tags: arrays, while-loop, binary, decimal

I don't understand what hv i done wrong here.My method might be a bit unconventional bt i feel it shud give the solution just fine,bt it is not!!

```
    int c;
printf("Enter the decimal number:");
scanf("%d",&c);
int d=c;
int j;
int k=0;
while(d>=1){
    k++;
    d/=2;
}
j=k-1;
int arr[k];
while(j>=0){
    arr[j]=c%2;
    j--;
    
    c/=2;
}
    printf("Binary number is:");
for(int l=0;l<=j;l++){
    printf("%d",arr[l]);
}
```

This is the code.Pl do help me!!